# SSIS ScriptResults.Failure vs Dts.Events.FireError - default behavour?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, ssis-2012, script-task

I am debugging my package within Visual Studio 2015.

If my script task ends with ScriptResults.Failure, package execution halts when the script finishes, ie the next task in Control flow does not execute.

If my script task raises a Dts.Events.FireError event ( even if the script continues and ends with a ScriptResults.Success), package execution also halts when the script finishes, ie the next task in Control flow does not execute.

I have not created an OnError event handler.

Either has the desired effect. I also note that if I raise the fire-error event and set task as failure, both are recorded in Progress as Exceptions.

I prefer the raise-event as I can specify an event error message, though I note that, for taskresults, messages can also be returned via the ExecutionValue Property.

Both methods do have the same effect of halting execution.
I have read from Documentation ... "Use the TaskResult property of the Dts object in Script task code to notify the package of the success or failure of the Script task." So it sounds like, by setting this property, some kind of TaskResult event is raised.

I can only assume that there are certain events which are considered as exceptions as the default behaviour (ie OnError event handler not created). Is this documented or defined anywhere?

And is there a recommended way ? ( both FireError AND taskresult failure?)